# woocommerce adding loop banner after every 3rd row of product gallery

Tags: woocommerce, static, block, banner, woothemes

I have product gallery pages with rows of 2 products and a standard view of 16 products per page (8 rows).

I want my product gallery pages to show a static block or banner under every third row.

Like this:

```
ROW 1
ROW 2
ROW 3
Banner/BLOCK
ROW 4
ROW 5
ROW 6
Banner/BLOCK
```

This shows exactly what I want:

[image: a]

Comment: What you did till now? What is your code? What you used till now?

Comment: hi timi this is my code ->                                                                   <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start();
  $product_count=0;
  woocommerce_product_subcategories();
  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

     if( is_product_category('All') && $product_count % 6==0 && $product_count!=0)
    {
    ?>
    <div class="club_offer">
     </div>
    <?php
    }
 wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); $product_count++;

 endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

Comment: it is in archive-product.php in my theme..